# remove site mobile master page from asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an asp.net site I just finished, I am using a wrap bootstrap theme so I have no need for a site.mobile.master page. How can I remove it completely? My site is fully responsive so I dont want it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Open Web.config, 
in `<system.web>` add the flowing:

```
<browserCaps>
  <result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  <filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
</browserCaps>
```