# Web Page will not display when viewed on mobile device

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a an aspx web application designed using bootstrap.  The site uses a master page and there is a Script Manager on the master page.  I use a Telerik RadWindowsManager on several of the form and all works as designed when viewing the application on my desktop.  I can resize the screen and the controls will react as expected.

The problem is when I view the web site on an I-Phone 6 I get the yellow screen crash advising the RAdWindowsManager requires a ScriptManager.

I can correct the problem if I remove the the script manager and all of my script reference from the master page and place them on the web page, but I lose the advantages of the Master Page.

Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is there a Site.Mobile.Master (that doesn't have a ScriptManager) that is unnecessarily taking over on mobile browsers?

Comment: No there is nothing in the site mobile master

Comment: Is that the problem? I must admit I've not used them before myself, but these links pointed towards that possibly being your problem...

https://forums.asp.net/t/2103641.aspx?Script+Manager+Error (see the last post)
https://forums.asp.net/t/2138112.aspx?Disable+the+site+mobile+master

Comment: I copied the content of my site master into the mobile site master and seems to have fixed the issue when I do the F12 and chose the browser profile as a  windows phone.  Will move from desktop to development environment and see what happens

Comment: Maybe just try removing Site.Mobile.Master completely, and the crash should just go away? (Again, I'm not 100% on how the Mobile master page is wired into the project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On mobile browsers the `Site.Mobile.Master` page in the project will be used instead of the main `Site.Master` page which contains the required `ScriptManager` references, causing the page to crash.

Try removing the the `Site.Mobile.Master` from your project, or at least preventing it from being used, and you should be left with a responsive web application, that runs happily in desktop and mobile browsers.

These links may help when it comes to getting rid of / turning off the `Site.Mobile.Master` page.

[remove site mobile master page from asp.net web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928052/remove-site-mobile-master-page-from-asp-net-web-application)

[In Visual Studio 2015 I would like to remove site.mobile.master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734652/in-visual-studio-2015-i-would-like-to-remove-site-mobile-master)

Comment: Thanks @Ted used the web.config to disbale the mobile master all is working as designed now.